# Create a portable Firefox

Tags: windows, firefox, portable

I have the .exe installation file for Firefox and I want to create a portable version for it as in my laptop any external software installed in C drive does not run.

How can I create a portable version of Firefox from this exe file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can download [Mozilla Firefox, Portable Edition](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable) and then use [MozBackup](http://mozbackup.jasnapaka.com/) to backup your current Firefox profile (if needed) from installed Firefox on your C drive and transfer it to your Portable Firefox. :-)

Used this approach some years ago and worked very well. Result is fully working Firefox portable with all your settings, bookmarks etc. from your old installation.

Answer (score 0):

For Linux, I created a download script here:  https://gist.github.com/rubo77/b999c1bc6d10ab802536